# How to stop this code from selecting only 50 records and instead select the all?

Tags: c#, silverlight-4.0

```
[OperationContract]
        public List<AlumniRegDetails> GetRecord()


  {
        using (Entities context = new Entities())
        {
            return (from c in context.Alumni_Registration 
                    select new AlumniRegDetails
                    { 
                        RegNo=c.RegNo,
                        Name=c.Name,
                        Gender=c.Gender,
                        Ay_Yr= c.AY_ID,
                        CellNo= c.CellNo,
                        BranchId=c.BranchId,
                        EmailId=c.EmailId,
                        facebookId=c.FacebookId,
                        LinkedID=c.LiknedInId,
                        googlePlusID=c.GooglePlusId,
                        Address=c.Address,
                       CountryId=c.CountryId,
                       StateId=c.StateId,
                       City=c.CityId,
                        Designation=c.DesginationId,
                        Occupation=c.OccupationId,

                    }).Take<AlumniRegDetails>(50).ToList<AlumniRegDetails>();
        }
    }
```

i have this code written in Service.svc.cs file in Silverlight.
This code of line---Take(50).ToList();let me retrieve 50 records from Database.
My requirement is it should retrieve all the records from the database without any limitations.
Can anyone correct me?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `Take` and it will return all the records. Keep the `ToList()` if you need a `List<T>`.

Answer (score 1):

}).Take(50).ToList();

==>

}).ToList();

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
}).Take<AlumniRegDetails>(50).ToList<AlumniRegDetails>();
```

with

```
}).ToList<AlumniRegDetails>();
```